# Wordpress widget title coding

Tags: widgets, title

I have a problem with wordpress widget titles, some widgets are not affected by theme custom encoding.

Here is the codes;

```
function ecce_widget_title($title){
if( empty( $title ) )
return ' ';
else 
$title = explode(' ', $title,2);
$titleNew = '<div class="title_w"><div class="widget-baslik-ilk"><h3>'.$title[0].'</h3></div><h3>'.$title[1].'</h3></div>';
return $titleNew; 
}
add_filter('widget_title', 'ecce_widget_title');
```

All widget's titles must be look like this; https://i.stack.imgur.com/97UHy.png

But some widget's titles look like this (just text); https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXMwA.png

Where am i doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is pretty simple: Some widgets do have a title, while others don't. As long as the title filter is present, it works. Example of what the plugin might have:

```
echo apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
```

If that filter is not present, there won't be a title.

Comment: Thank you for reply, what can be done for a solution?

Comment: If the widgets are created by a plugin or theme, you could contact the author(s), most people are pretty receptive.  Outside of that you're looking at modifying the code that generates the widgets.